# use FTP without temporary files

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am familiar with the regular procedure when using batch ftp scripts. for example:

```
@echo off
(
echo open HOST
echo USERNAME
echo PASSWORD
echo dir
echo get file
echo bye
)>script.ftp
ftp -s:script.ftp
```

but the other day I came across a forum where the user said something about connecting to the ftp server using pipes, and I cant seem to remember what the exact code was. I know it goes something like:

```
@echo off
(
echo open HOST
echo USERNAME
echo PASSWORD
echo dir
echo get file
echo bye
)|ftp -s
```

or something along that line.
and before you say I should check my history, I was "incognito" in google chrome.

My question: is the second batch file possible? and if so, how?

Comment: Why not trying it youself?? The `-s` switch of the `ftp` command is intended to specify a file (type `ftp -?` for help); omitting the file will throw an error. I think you should simply omit also the `-s` switch.

Comment: i treid omitting the "-s" switch. still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were looking for [this DOSTips post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6574).

```
@echo off
(
echo open HOST
echo user USERNAME
echo PASSWORD
echo dir
echo get file
echo bye
)|ftp -n
```

The `-n` option suppresses auto-login upon initial connection, so the `echo` commands get immediately processed by ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the FTP mode of `curl`...

```
curl -u user:password 'ftp://somefile' -o somefile
```

Comment: I could, but I'm trying to use the built in ftp client only, so it could work on pc's without the curl library.